# Javascript not working with onchange event of multi select dropdownlist in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2, html-select

I have below Razor Code in ASP.NET MVC view

```
<div id="rolesValues" class="case-assignment-hide">       
        @Html.DropDownList("ddlRoleValues", new SelectList(@Model.Roles, "Key", "Value"), new {@id= "ddlRoleValues", @class = "form-control case-assignment-rule-use-values", multiple = "multiple" })
        <span class="field-validation-valid help-block" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

And below is my javascript to catch change event for above `dropdownlist` which I put inside `$(document).ready(function ()`

```
 $("#ddlRoleValues").on("change", function () {
            alert('I got the hit');

        });
```

I have noticed that this event is not getting fired whenever there is change in selection of `dropdownlist` item.

and below is the HTML rendered in browser

```
<div class="col-sm-4 case-assignment-rule-value-selection">
    <div class="select2-container select2-container-multi form-control case-assignment-rule-values" id="s2id_ddlRoleValues">
        <ul class="select2-choices">
            <li class="select2-search-choice">
                <div>Manager</div>
                <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="select2-search-field">
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" id="s2id_autogen1" style="width: 34px;">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <select class="form-control case-assignment-rule-values select2-offscreen" id="CaseAssignmentRules[0].RuleValues" multiple="multiple" name="CaseAssignmentRules[0].RuleValues" tabindex="-1" data-val="true" data-val-required="This field is required.">
        <option value="aae">Manager</option>
        <option value="aad">Manager Supervisor</option>
        <option value="ab1">Accommodations Manager</option>
        <option value="ab0">Service Representative</option>
        <option value="84d">demo</option>
        <option value="ab2">Employee</option>
        <option value="ab4">Human Resource</option>
        <option value="aaf">Case Manager</option>
        <option value="ab3">Supervisor</option>
    </select>
    <span class="field-validation-valid help-block" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="CaseAssignmentRules[0].RuleValues"></span>
</div>
```

Am I missing something??

Comment: Hi Vijay, I can get your code to work as is. Do you have any errors in the F12 console? Are you including the jquery scripts, and in the right place/order?

Comment: Yes I had test with all possibilities, but got no luck. No Error or warning on console too

Comment: Please post the HTML that gets rendered for this dropdownlist in the browser.  It may receive a different name and ID than you're expecting, due to how the `select` control is rendered in a form.

Comment: Ok lets dig a little further.  Please show the full js script for this function, what you have posted is missing some brackets.  Also, please tell us where that script is included (in the index page? in it's own file..? then show the list of included scripts.

Comment: Also, please post the model definition for 'Roles'

Comment: Role is a dictionary which is bind to dropdownlist, the js doesnt has much lines, If I put alert before onchange event it get hit but not inside onchange event function.

Comment: Please post the actual rendered html of the select, and the Roles model (or the model that contains the Roles property).

Comment: I updated question with rendered HTML code

Comment: @VijayKumbhoje It seems like you've posted the wrong html: there are no elements with id `rolesValues` or `ddlRoleValues` which you mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Erik Philip says it's true that my code generating auto ID but we can apply event on class instead of Id. Here how I achieved it. I added below line in my `$(document).ready(function ()`

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.case-assignment-rule-value-selection').find('select.case-assignment-rule-values').select2().on("change", function () {
  listToFilter(this);
);
 var listToFilter = function (e) {

        var selectedLength = $(e).select2('data');
}
```

Passed event to `function` and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try using the class instead of id 
$(document).on("change", ".case-assignment-rule-values", function () {
alert('I got the hit');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your MVC code:

```
<div id="rolesValues" class="case-assignment-hide">       
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlRoleValues", new SelectList(@Model.Roles, "Key", "Value"), new {@id= "ddlRoleValues", @class = "form-control case-assignment-rule-use-values", multiple = "multiple" })
    <span class="field-validation-valid help-block" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

Should produce 2 elements with the id of `rolesValues` and `ddlRoleValues`.  However, those Ids are no where to be found in your produced HTML.

So based on this information your question is *unanswerable* because no amount of code will be able to select any of these elements since they do not exist.

Comment: actually instead of I'd I passed event dynamically and the issue is resolved.